# How to set animation on recyclerview

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-cardview

I am creating an app using new API 21 (Lollipop) i am setting animation slide_in_left on recyclerview to animate cardview 1 by 1 but when items appear they will come together and i want them to slide_in_left 1 by 1 and 2nd i am animating toolbar bar to hide/show its working but problem is when i scroll up and when recyclerview stops then it will hide and same case when scroll down, i want to hide/show toolbar when scroll starts anyone help me. Thanks in advance

belowis Myadapter class for recyclerview animation

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<PersonData> peopleDataSet;
private Context context;
View view;
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textViewName;
    TextView textViewEmail;
    ImageView imageViewIcon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        this.textViewEmail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        this.imageViewIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<PersonData> people,Context context) {
    this.peopleDataSet = people;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                       int viewType) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cards_layout, parent, false);

    view.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.myOnClickListener);
  setAnimation(view);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

    TextView textViewName = holder.textViewName;
    TextView textViewEmail = holder.textViewEmail;
    ImageView imageView = holder.imageViewIcon;

    textViewName.setText(peopleDataSet.get(listPosition).getName());
    textViewEmail.setText(peopleDataSet.get(listPosition).getEmail());
    imageView.setImageResource(peopleDataSet.get(listPosition).getImage());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return peopleDataSet.size();
}
/**
 * Here is the key method to apply the animation
 */
private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate)
{
    // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);

}
```

below is toolbar code

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (dy > 0) {
                toolbar.animate()
                        .translationY(-toolbar.getBottom())
                        .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                        .start();



            } else {

                toolbar.animate()
                        .translationY(0)
                        .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                        .start();


            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `RecyclerView` does not support animation while scrolling with `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator`.

If you want to achieve one by one animation of RecyclerView items, you should animate each `viewHolder.itemView` inside `onBindView` method. Keeping track of last animated position is important to avoid animation when scrolling down, unless that is not your intention though.

Here is simple alpha animation I did:

```
public interface RecyclerViewItemOnScrollAnimator {
    public void onAnimateViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position);
    public void onPrepareToAnimateViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder);
}
```

Here is implementation of the `Animator` (sort of, couldn't come up with better name)

```
public class RecyclerViewScrollAnimator implements RecyclerViewItemOnScrollAnimator{
    private final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private final Interpolator mInterpolator;
    int mLastAnimatedPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

    public RecyclerViewScrollAnimator(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mInterpolator = InterpolatorUtil.loadInterpolator(recyclerView.getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimateViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        onPrepareToAnimateViewHolder(viewHolder);
        if(shouldAnimateOrPrepare(position)){
            ViewCompat.animate(viewHolder.itemView)
                    .alpha(1)
                    .setInterpolator(mInterpolator)
                    .setDuration(300).start();
        }
        mLastAnimatedPosition = position;
    }

    private boolean shouldAnimateOrPrepare(int position) {
       return mLastAnimatedPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION || mLastAnimatedPosition < position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareToAnimateViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
     // do some stuff if needed before animation
     if(shouldAnimateOrPrepare(position)){
        ViewCompat.setAlpha(viewHolder.itemView, 0);
     }
    }
    //clear animation if needed
    private void cancelAnimationAt(int position) {
      RecyclerView.ViewHolder v =  mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(position);
      if(!isVisible(position) || v != null){
          if(v != null) {
              Log.i("cancelAnimationAt", " canceling "+position);
              //cancelAnimation(v.itemView);
          }
      }

    }

    private void cancelAnimation(View v) {
       if(v != null) {
        v.clearAnimation();
        v.setAnimation(null);
        ViewCompat.animate(v).cancel();
      }
    }

    private boolean isVisible(int position){
        return position >= mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() && position <= mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    }

}
```

And here is how you use it in your `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh, int position) {
      if(getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
          bindItem(vh, position-1); // position only if no header otherwise position-1
          mRecyclerViewAnimator.onAnimateViewHolder(vh, position);
      }
      else return; // don't bind the header
    }
```

Now you should modify the code inside `onAnimateViewHolder()` to use your animation resource. That's trivial.

On your `Toolbar` toggling, I suggest you to use this [library](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView). It has really handy scroll callbacks for your purpose.

Comment: You should use `onViewAttachedToWindow` instead of onBind. RecyclerView won't rebind an item if it is cached and valid.